# What's the recommended way to make a Scala project available to the community?

Tags: scala, maven, publishing

I am currently writing a configuration file library (sort of Configgy replacement). For the moment, it's alpha release and stays well on GitHub. However, when the project will be stable enough, I plan to make the resulting JAR file widely available.

On Ruby I used the central *[RubyGems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems)* repository for that purpose. However, I have no idea what's the equivalent. I was thinking about using a *[Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)* repository, but which one? And how?

I am using *[SBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Build_Tool)* 0.7.7 and I have no experience with *Maven*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the most usage, I'd publish it to a Maven repository.  There's the Scala Tools repository at http://scala-tools.org/ and there's Maven Central at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html.

There's also Scala's sbaz: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/93, which is similar to Ruby's gem.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the credentials to publish in any of these repositories ?

Comment: If you want to host it on the Scala Tools repository, email admin@scala-tools.org.  The requirements for hosting and what you need to provide are listed on their website at the link above.  Hosting on Maven Central can be done via https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide.  Also, Scala Tools repository syncs to Maven Central, so if you host on Scala Tools, it will end up in both repositories.

Comment: There are instructions on publishing to scala-tools here: http://scala-tools.org/

Comment: Thanks. Sbaz adoption seems to be low, any reasons ?

Comment: Probably because of the maturity of Maven.  Here's a blog post that has the same conclusion: http://djhworld.posterous.com/why-isnt-the-scala-bazaar-sbaz-more-actively

Answer (score 6):

As you already are using GitHub you can release your JAR file as a Maven repository in your own GitHub itself! There is no need to host anywhere.

Read the following articles.

- *[Hosting Maven Repositories on GitHub](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/)*
- *[Maven Repositories on GitHub](http://chkal.blogspot.com/2010/09/maven-repositories-on-github.html)*

Comment: I think this is a good approach when first proving out a project and getting initial feedback, but setting up a third party repo (especially in enterprises with draconian nexus mirrors) can really serve as an impediment to adoption. As obnoxious and roundabout a process as it is, getting your artifact into Maven Central really does make it easier for your users to use.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are pretty good, but here's a checklist:

- Announce it and new releases of it on scala-announce@googlegroups.com
- Announce it and new releases of it on [implicit.ly](http://implicit.ly/) (you'll need a [posterous](https://posterous.com/) account); I think there's an SBT plugin to do this too
- Publish it to a maven repository -- SBT makes it easy, see the other answers
- If open source, make the code available on [GitHub](http://github.com) -- though there are other places, most projects are there, and quite a few that started elsewhere are there now
- You may wish to use sbaz *as well*; the problem with sbaz is the lack of good dependency control -- in fact, that's the problem with most package systems